# Creating Ionic project always download files from internet

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I'm newbie in developing Ionic project. I'm all set with the sample template projects available and i'm good with that. Managed to deploy and able to run their examples.

When I try to create a new blank project **[ ionic start LoginDemo blank ]**, using CMD in windows, it started to download the ionic app base files from internet.

when i tried to create a platform for android **[ ionic platform add android ]** 
, it starts to download all the resources required to run the android version from internet.

**So my question is,** 
whenever we create a new project in ionic, all the required files are downloaded from the internet. Is there any way to setup a standard dev enviroment by downloading the files once and using it when creating new project instead of downloading each time from the internet or this is the only way *[download files each time from the internet on creating project]*.

any clarification regarding this is much appreciated. !! Thank you for all your help.

If i'm not clear kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can, as long as you have the configurations correct for the CLI to run properly.  I however would advise against this.  When it downloads all of the files, it gets the latest, stable release of each of the files.  This helps squash potential bugs that are fixed in some of the patches of this file.

As a potential solution to your problem, write services/controllers/directives that are flexible enough to work in most environments.  Creating template services and helper methods can be just as efficient if they are coded correctly.

For example, for my projects I want to have a way to present a nice dialog box to the user.  This is a pretty universal feature, so I wrote a service that did it for me.  I use this in all my apps and it increases my efficiency because I don't have to rewrite the same code over and over.  Its just a matter of copying the file into my directory and referencing it.

Here's my example:

```
var module = angular.module('PopupModule', []);

module.service('PopupService', ['$ionicPopup', function ($ionicPopup) {
    var factory = {};

factory.ConfirmDialog = function (title, contents, actionName) {
    var data = {};

    return $ionicPopup.prompt({
        title: title,
        inputType: 'input',
        inputPlaceholder: contents
    });
}

factory.MessageDialog = function (message) {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Message',
        template: message
    });
};

factory.InitializeModal = function ($ionicModal, $scope, templateUrl) {
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(templateUrl, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up',
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    $scope.openModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.show();
    };

    $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };

    //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
    });

    // Execute action on hide modal
    $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function () {
        // Execute action
    });

    // Execute action on remove modal
    $scope.$on('modal.removed', function () {
        // Execute action
    });
};

return factory;
}]);
```

Comment: so you are advising to download all the required files repeated when you create new project ?